# Check whether an ID's classifier/attribute changes from one month to the next and if it does, create a list of changes

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with a "DATE" column, an "ID" column and a "CLASSIFIER" column, as follows:

```
set.seed(11)
Data <- data.frame(
        DATE = sample(seq(as.Date("2010-02-01"), length=12, by="1 month") - 1,50,replace = TRUE),
        ID = sample(1:9,50,replace = TRUE),
        CLASSIFIER = sample(c("yes", "no"), 50, replace = TRUE)
      )
```

The output looks like this:

```
        DATE ID CLASSIFIER
1 2010-03-31  3        yes
2 2010-04-30  3         no
3 2010-04-30  4         no
4 2010-06-30  4        yes
5 2010-09-30  2         no
6 2010-11-30  5         no
```

I would now like to get a list of those IDs whose classifier changes from one date to the next. In other words, I want a list of all
IDs (including the respective date) which change from `"yes"` to `"no"` or from `"no"` to `"yes"` from one month to the next. For clarification, by from one month to the next I am speaking strictly chronologically - the ranking of the dates in the data.frame should be irreleveant. So, a change for a given ID may, for example, only occur on 2010-02-28 if there exists an entry for the same ID on 2010-01-31 with the opposite CLASSIFIER. Ideally, the list would also state the nature of the change (i.e. from `"no"` to `"yes"` or from `"yes"` to `"no"`)
From the output example above (first two lines), if ID "3" has the `"yes"` `CLASSIFIER`on 2010-03-31 and the `"no"` `CLASSIFIER` on 2010-04-30, the list should state ID "3", "2010-04-30" and something like "yes to no". ID "4" in row 3 and 4 would not qualify as a change, because the change did not occur from one month to the next chronologically speaking.

Would someone please help me with this?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Kind regards,

C.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear on your expected output, but perhaps something like this will get you started?

```
library(tidyverse)
Data %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(status = if_else(
        CLASSIFIER != lag(CLASSIFIER),
        sprintf("change: %s to %s", lag(CLASSIFIER), CLASSIFIER),
        "nochange"))
## A tibble: 50 x 4
## Groups:   ID [9]
#   DATE          ID CLASSIFIER status
#   <date>     <int> <fct>      <chr>
# 1 2010-04-30     3 no         NA
# 2 2010-07-31     3 yes        change: no to yes
# 3 2010-02-28     9 no         NA
# 4 2010-02-28     1 yes        NA
# 5 2010-10-31     2 no         NA
# 6 2010-07-31     5 yes        NA
# 7 2010-04-30     6 yes        NA
# 8 2010-12-31     3 no         change: yes to no
# 9 2010-08-31     4 yes        NA
#10 2010-01-31     1 no         change: yes to no
## … with 40 more rows
```

Cross check: For `ID=3` there is a change from `CLASSIFIER="no"` to `"yes"` between `Date="2010-04-03"` and `Date="2010-07-31"` in rows 1 and 2. For `ID=1` there is change from `CLASSIFIER="yes"` to `"no"` in rows 4 and 10.

Comment: Thank you very much @Maurits Evers! I just realised I should have used set.seed()... So, unfortunately, I cannot answer your question. Although I must admit I cannot  understand what your code exactly does, but it does not seem to take only changes from the prior month to the next, does it? But your answer helps me a lot, I had no idea how to approach the problem, but with your answer, I will figure it out, thanks again for that input!

Comment: *"but it does not seem to take only changes from the prior month to the next, does it"* Yes, that is exactly what `CLASSIFIER != lag(CLASSIFIER)` does; it compares the value of `CLASSIFIER` with that from the previous entry (for a specific `ID`). If that's not what you're after please clarify in your main post by providing your **expected output** for some minimal sample dataset. That way we avoid confusion and ambiguities and it will make it a lot easier for everyone to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @cthulhukk Can you please edit your post and add your expected output!

Comment: If I preface my data.frame code with set.seed(11) and then run my and your code, the 7th row prints a change from yes to no on 2010-02-28 (see below), although there is no entry for identifier 3 on 2010-01-31 from which a change could happen. Writing these lines, it occurs to me that I was speaking chronologically, while your answer is based the notion of "in the previous entry". Is that possible? Sorry in this case for the confusion, will clarify in my question above.

`DATE          ID CLASSIFIER status                     
7 2010-02-28     4 no         change: yes to no`